# Can I send a request(http)/connect to a URL ( a JSP page on some server) through a iPhone App

Tags: java, ios, jsp, ios4

I have a task to complete. 
I need to access a JSP page on some server using http: by passing request attributes and capture the response in iPhone App.

It's like Java in iPhone.

Is it possile? Please help out.

Comment: So in one sentence: you want to make load an URL? As in using [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) recommended.